# Cloud Firestore, separate individual database

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible for an App running on multiple devices to have their own individual Firestore database, which the user of the device can access with their own login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You would typically have each user access their own collection or subcollection within the database, identified by their Firebase Authentication user id, then protect that collection with [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication).

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible using MongoDB Atlas? Or is there any other way of doing it, so as to allow the user to pay for the database services as they use it?

Comment: I don't know about those.  You should ask a different question and tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

No. You would make a database with a child for every user to keep all his data. This structure is pretty common In apps. You could also add the security features that only a user can access his own data to make sure it’s individual